# node express content-disposition

Tags: node.js, express, content-disposition, requestjs

I want to force the browser to download a file from an external storage, given an url.
I implemented this express controller post action:

```
var download = function(req, res) {
    request(req.body.url).on('response', function(response) {
        res.set({
            'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename=' + req.body.filename,
            'Content-Type': response.headers['content-type']
        });
    })
    .pipe(res);
};
```

I don't know why the browser always receive a "inline" instead of "attachment", avoiding me to download the file.

In this case I use express and request, the server is hosted on Heroku and the server that hosts files is FilePicker.

Comment: FWIW, your code will do the wrong thing in case the filename contains whitespace, certain delimiters, or non-ASCII characters. See RFC 6266.

Answer (score 12):

I'm searching around for the very same thing. [Express' documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.download) shows a very simple helper method right out of the box:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/download', function(req, res) {
  res.download('/path/to/your_file.pdf');
});
```